# Using Google Drive's Resumable Upload REST API to upload file into parallel chunks does not work?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-drive-api

[Resumable Upload Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable)

If I change my code to send the chunks sequentially, i.e not issue the HTTP PUT requests in parallel with other HTTP PUT requests, everything works as expected.

When parallel execution is introduced though, a lot of the HTTP requests that were made return with a status code of 503 - Service Unavailable.

The same code I'm using is used for many different cloud providers, such as Dropbox for instance, so I don't think it's an issue of code, especially when sequentially everything works. (I've made sure parallel execution does not share any "mutable" state).

Why does Google not allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this would be a feature request as it's currently not possible, you can star this [Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/220523936) as someone has already requested this and provided reasons about why it would be useful.